Why doesn't --cycle goes back to the first point, when the points are labeled using the blochsphere package
I want to draw a shape inside a Bloch Sphere using the blochsphere package. Here's a MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{blochsphere}

\begin{document}

\begin{blochsphere}
    \drawBallGrid[style={draw,opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}
    \labelPolar[labelmark=true]{plus}{90}{90}
    \labelPolar[labelmark=true]{plusi}{90}{0}
    \labelPolar[labelmark=true]{minusi}{90}{180}
    \labelPolar[labelmark=true]{minus}{90}{270}
    \draw[dashed, red, fill=orange] (plus) -- (plusi) -- (minus) -- (minusi) --cycle;
\end{blochsphere}
\end{document}

And here's the result:

As you can see, the path doesn't cycle back to (plus) as I thought it should've. I think the fact that I can't get a filled surface between these 4 points is probably linked to this.
Did I do an obvious mistake? How to fix this?

The path is not one continuous path. It's three disconnected straight lines (between nodes). cycle doesn't work that way.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{blochsphere}
\begin{document}
\begin{blochsphere}
\drawBallGrid[style={draw, opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}
\labelPolar[labelmark=true]{plus}{90}{90}
\labelPolar[labelmark=true]{plusi}{90}{0}
\labelPolar[labelmark=true]{minusi}{90}{180}
\labelPolar[labelmark=true]{minus}{90}{270}
\draw[dashed, red, fill=orange] (plus.center) -- (plusi.center) -- (minus.center) -- (minusi.center) --cycle;
\end{blochsphere}
\end{document}


